# Why did Community approve this edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, community-user

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5739792

The person editing it clearly states that it's a comment (in my opinion, it should have been a separate answer). I rejected the edit in a review, but the Community user approved it. What's the deal?

Also, would it be appropriate to roll back even if the original poster modified the edit?

Comment: Most likely, the OP accepted the edit.

Comment: But it looks like Community approved before OP edited.

Comment: Notice the notation "Stijn Bernards reviewed this 2 hours ago: Edit", above the Community accept.

Comment: I wouldn't roll it back.  The original version is not an improvement.  I cleaned it up a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OP picked the *Improve Edit* option, which carries an implicit *Approve*. In that case Community is instructed to accept the suggestion, so that the reviewer can add their own edit on top.

The reason the Community User accepts and not the reviewer is that it requires a veto vote; the Community User is a moderator and has such a vote. That way the edit is applied immediately.

Of course, the OP has such a veto vote too, but to keep things simple, for all *Improve Edit* and *Reject and Edit* actions the Community User casts the vote instead.

You can tell this is what happened from the suggested edit vote result summary:

> [image: vote result]

Had the OP picked *Reject and Edit* the Community User would have voted to Reject instead. You'll also note that if you mouse over the timestamps you'll see that the two votes were cast at exactly the same time.

The OP made several additional edits; the result requires cleaning up, not rolling back. Lucky for us Robert Harvey already did this.